# Google Maps Lat Long Picker Showing Logo but not Map

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps, jquery-ui

OK seems to be a weird one that I'm not entirely sure how to debug. Any help where I can get started would be ace.

So I'm attempting to use this jQuery plugin for google maps that allows you to drag a marker and get a lat long returned (if you know of a better solution doing the same thing I'll take that!) Link here: https://github.com/wimagguc/jquery-latitude-longitude-picker-gmaps

The documentation is sparse, but for what it is it shouldn't need too much.

I'm attempting to use this map in a jQuery UI Tab within a Bootstrap framework. I'm also hoping to use the bootstrap grid to size the width of the google map. So variable width and Tabs always seems to ruin everything so could be either of these.

Now for all this I've kind of got something working with the basic html:

```
<div class="row gllpLatlonPicker">

    <input type="hidden" class="gllpLatitude" value="56.35319217617958"/>
    <input type="hidden" class="gllpLongitude" value="-2.87078857421875"/>
    <input type="hidden" class="gllpZoom" value="11"/>
    <div class="col-md-12 gllpMap" style="height: 250px; margin: 15px;"></div>

</div><!--- /.row --->
```

So the result is that I get the right shape of grey box with the Google logo and terms showing, but no map, what's even weirder is when I go to open the browser debug console the map appears. Or if the console is open I get the grey box and it appears when I close the console.

Any ideas?

There is no more code, this plugin has written it's own initialization within the .js so there's nothing to show in respect of that.

Let me know if there was something else I should be showing, if this didn't involve jQuery UI, Bootstrap, as well as this plugin and such I'd throw together a fiddle for you all. If you point me towards a tool that does all that I'll build it up to give something to work with.

Reading the intertubes I noticed a few people having issues in Android app development with the API key, but that doesn't seem to apply here.

Thanks.

Comment: just like all plugins ... if the documentation isn't any good, find another one that has proper docs. Getting location from a map marker is not difficult , and neither is setting locations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is a common problem, I probably just didn't word it well enough.

The comment was very helpful as it caused me to go find another plugin and then experience the exact same scenario. So that was fun. But it triggered the thought that this wasn't a plugin problem and narrowed it down to the use of tabs (because tabs always causes problems).

I was attempting to load the map into a hidden element on load. It needed a kick to get map to show up, so I called a function on the map on the selection of the tab and voile I don't have to microwave any frogs tonight.

For future reference, when in doubt, it's probably jQuery UI's fault.